# can't navigate to nested route but browser url gets updated

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

I have some simple CRUD pages for users (and use Vuetify). So

- /users will render the users list
- /users/:id will render the user profile

After setting up my nested routes in the router config I'm navigating to those nested routes but my currently rendered view doesn't update although the browser url gets updated. Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new Vue project with Vue Router
2. Add Vuetify to the project
3. Update the App.vue file to

.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

4. Create a users view

.

```
<template>
  <v-btn to="/users/1">Navigate</v-btn>
</template>
```

5. Create a user view

.

```
<template>
  <p>User</p>
</template>
```

6. Setup the routes

.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    redirect: "/users"
  },
  {
    path: "/users",
    component: Users,
    children: [
      {
        path: ":id",
        component: User
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

7. Run the application and call the root url (`http://localhost:8080`)
8. You should get redirected to `/users`
9. Click the button
10. The url gets updated but the application won't navigate to the user view

How can I fix that? I would expect a rendered user view for `http://localhost:8080/users/1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the idea of nested route, when using the `children` path to a component, it will try to render the `children` in the `<router-view>` of that component. This would mean that It will try to render the **User** view in the `<router-view>` of **Users** components (not **App.vue**), but it not found any in **Users** so thats why nothing happens.

More information can be found here :https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

In order to archive your goal

> /users will render the users list
>
> /users/:id will render the user
>   profile

I think you can define the `Users` and `User` component differently
 Like this in routes.js :

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/users'
  },
  {
    path: '/users',
    component: Users
  },
  {
    path: '/users/:id',
    component: User
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are defining the children route you have to declare `<router-view></router-view>` in the parent component.

> Users.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    Users Page
    <router-view></router-view>   // ---> define this
  </div>
</template>
```

> User.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    USER {{ $route.params.id }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: oh, thanks for your reply. I already declared the router view in my app.vue file ... I'll update my question

Comment: it's not about declaring it in app.vue!
in your routes.js whenever you declare a children array for a route you have to decalre router-view in the parent component.